# Who are the 3rd party 4e D&D providers?

Tags: dnd-4e, games-industry

Who are the 3rd party 4e D&D providers. What type of material do they do. One company per answer please.

As this is a community wiki the answers (and votes) will gauge community views on their materials.

Answer (score 4):

Meta-answer: WotC has a [catalog of third-party partners](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4dnd/partnerships). There is a somewhat larger list [here](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Partnerships.aspx); at first glance, the second list includes foreign language novel partners and such along with people producing 4e material.

Neither list includes publishers who've chosen not to sign up for the GSL, such as Kobold Quarterly. The lists also appear to be out of date; for example, Nevermet Press uses the GSL and is not listed.

Another selection of third party products can be found [on RPGNow.](http://www.rpgnow.com/index.php?filters=0_0_0_44281) This list is composed of products that have been tagged as 4e products, and may include non-rules material -- e.g., [650 Fantasy City Encounter Seeds & Hooks](http://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=83932&filters=0_0_0_44281) is completely mechanics-free.

Answer (score 3):

**Goodman Games** publishes sourcebooks and modules. Their online catalog page is [here](http://www.goodman-games.com/4eproducts.html).

Comment: I see Goodman mentioned a lot. What do they do that stands out?

Comment: Cheap and prolific, mainly. They were a steady source of modules in the 3E days for D&D, and have maintained that role.

Answer (score 2):

Enhanced 4E.

First publication is Combat in Motion. Available here: http://www.Enhanced4E.com

Answer (score 1):

**Mongoose Publishing** released a Tom-Clancy-esque setting for 4e called *Wraith Recon*. They're no longers supporting that version, and converting it to use their *RuneQuest II* system instead.